# jstree not building the tree

Tags: jstree

I am trying to build a tree from an xml file using jstree. I followed the documentation and looks like it is not working. Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\jstree\jstree_pre1.0_fix_1\jquery.jstree.js"></script>
    <Script Language="JavaScript">
  $(function () {  

     $("#demo2").jstree({   

         "xml_data" : {  

             "ajax" : {  

                 "url" : "books.xml" 

             },  

             "xsl" : "nest" 

         },  

         "plugins" : [ "themes", "xml_data" ]  

     });  
     }); 

</Script>

</head>
<body>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XML is not formatted in a way that jsTree can include it.

http://www.jstree.com/documentation/xml_data

Two types of XML structures are supported - flat and nested:

```
<!-- FLAT -->
<root>
    <item id="root_1" parent_id="0" state="closed">
        <content>
            <name><![CDATA[Node 1]]></name>
        </content>
    </item>
    <item id="node_2" parent_id="root_1">
        <content>
            <name><![CDATA[Node 2]]></name>
        </content>
    </item>
</root>

<!-- NESTED -->
<root>
    <item id="xml_1">
        <content><name><![CDATA[Root node 1]]></name></content>
        <item id="xml_2">
            <content><name><![CDATA[Child node 1]]></name></content>
        </item>
    </item>
</root>
```

An alternative is to bring the XML document in and convert it into JSON, then transform it into a valid JSON or HTML data format.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like container(#demo2) is missing. Try adding `<div id='demo2'></div>` under *body* tag.

Also make sure the jstree.js file is getting loaded correctly.

Comment: my browser stuck on saying Loading

Answer (score 0):

There is no such attribute for script called "language" (there may have been, but it's deprecated).

Place your code in script tags like the below code and try again

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Your Code Here
</script>
```

Comment: Add this as a sanity check in your script: $(document).ready(function() {
      alert($.jstree._themes);
}); Mine reads out something like: http://.../.../jstree/themes/ . This is to make sure the library is even loading correctly.

Comment: Another sanity check is: alert($().jquery);  Again, mine reads out something like 1.6.2

Comment: verified that libraries are loading

Answer (score 0):

Give a relative path instead of **"url" : "books.xml"**. Replace it with the current path like **"url" : "../Content/Xml/books.xml"**.
That might work.

Regards,
Amrutha